# HDFS user permission does not work correctly

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, acl

HDFS users can create/delete folders for each other, while the permission is set to `745` on `/user/username`.

I used the following commands to create users and set their permissions

```
useradd -m -g hdfs username
su hdfs
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /user/username
hdfs dfs -chown username:hdfs /user/username
hdfs dfs -chmod 745 /user/username
```

when `user1` executes: `hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/user2/from_user1`

```
The directory is created successfully
```

The same happens when `user1` tries to delete files from `/user/user2` while the permission is set to read only for the users in the same group.